# Socket output being truncated to the next file

Tags: python

I have this unlimited loop that is reading from a socket. Every minute, I change the location of the write to the next minute.

The problem is that my last line in the stream is getting truncated in the middle and put into the next file. Is there a way I can tell it to only stop at a newline instead of right in the middle?

```
while ok:
    filename1 = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("FILE.0000.%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.txt")
    path="/tmp/" + filename1
    file1 = open(path,"a")
    ready_to_read, ready_to_write, in_error = select.select(readers, [ ], readers, 300) 

    for s in ready_to_read: 
        line = s.recv(1024)
        if line:
            file1.write(line)
        else:
            ok = False

    file1.flush()
    file1.close()
```

Comment: by taking the rightmost part of the last linefeed, not writing it but storing it for the next file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one socket, `select` is not necessary. Use `makefile` and read lines:

```
handle = reader.makefile()
for line in handle:
    filename = "FILE.0000.{:%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M}.txt".format(datetime.datetime.now())
    with open(os.path.join('/tmp', filename), "a") as output:
        output.write(line)
```

Comment: This is perfect, Thank you. Very nice and clean.

Answer (score 0):

I would

- write only the leftmost part of the last linefeed
- keep a "last line" variable to write into the next file

For instance using `str.rpartition`:

```
>>> left_part,_,remaining_line = "a\nb\nc".rpartition("\n")
>>> left_part
'a\nb'
>>> remaining_line
'c'
```

like this:

```
remaining_line = ""
while ok:
    filename1 = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("FILE.0000.%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.txt")
    path="/tmp/" + filename1
    with open(path,"a") as f:
       if remaining_line:
          file1.write(remaining_line)

       for s in ready_to_read: 
           line = s.recv(1024)
           if line:
              left_part,_,remaining_line = line.rpartition("\n");
              file1.write(left_part)
              file1.write("\n")
           else:
              ok = False
```

note that you should do something with the last `remaining_line` (when `ok` is `False`) if needed.